# Looking to install Thunderbird 31.4

Tags: 14.04, ppa, thunderbird

I'm looking for a good PPA to pull the latest Thunderbird release (31.4).  I'm a noob and still finding my way.  Looked in Launchpad.  Found PPA:`ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`. I have Thunderbird already installed in my Ubuntu 14.04.  Do I need to uninstall the version I already have or can I add the PPA and install over the current installation? Looking for guidance.  Ciao! P.S. Hooray for new Thunderbird developments!

Comment: Canonical is not too slow about getting the current versions into their distributions, and 31.4 was released only yesterday.  Are you sure you really want to go through the effort of a manual load of Thunderbird instead of waiting a couple of days?

Comment: @CharlesGreen, you make a good point about waiting for the push from Canonical.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CharlesGreen. TB is now 31.1 on stock 14.04; unless you really need really badly NOW one of the updates, I would really advise to wait.

Anyway, your answer: after adding the PPA the packages will be updated with the PPA ones; no need to remove and reinstall. Just update and upgrade as per the PPA instruction and you have your package updated (and tracking the PPA from now on).

Going back is not so easy, though --- especially if the PPA start pulling dependencies and touching the configuration files. Sometime is plainly impossible... And depending on the PPA, then you can have problems in upgrading the system to a new version.

Said so, I use PPAs too --- but you have to be very selective and use them only if you really need the newer packages.

You can find a lot of info here: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and here: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: thanks for the references.  I will definitely read them.  Thanks!